# Classifying a sentence by the maximum number of classes contained in it

Tags: r, string

I have the following sentences:

```
sentences<-c("The color blue neutralizes orange yellow reflections.", 
         "Zod stabbed me with blue Kryptonite.", 
         "Because blue is your favourite colour.",
         "Red is wrong, blue is right.",
         "You and I are going to yellowstone.",
         "Van Gogh looked for some yellow at sunset.",
         "You ruined my beautiful green dress.",
         "There's nothing wrong with green.")
```

which I would like to classify according to the following classes:

```
A<-c("red")
B<-c("orange")
C<-c("yellow","yellowstone")
D<-c("blue")
E<-c("green")
```

The difficulty of this task is that first sentence, e.g., can be classified in `D`, `B`, `C` then the resulting classification should be `B+C+D`. The second and third sentence are simply `D`. The fourth sentence is both `A` and `D` and then `A+D`. The fifth sentence is `C` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way in base R (maybe a bit convoluted) :

```
list_col <- mget(LETTERS[1:5])

sapply(sentences, function(x) toString(names(Filter(function(y) 
           any(grepl(paste0("\\b", y, "\\b", collapse = "|"), x, 
               ignore.case = TRUE)), list_col))))


#The color blue neutralizes orange yellow reflections. 
#                                            "B, C, D" 
#                 Zod stabbed me with blue Kryptonite. 
#                                                  "D" 
#               Because blue is your favourite colour. 
#                                                  "D" 
#                         Red is wrong, blue is right. 
#                                               "A, D" 
#                  You and I are going to Yellowstone. 
#                                                  "C" 
#           Van Gogh looked for some yellow at sunset. 
#                                                  "C" 
#                 You ruined my beautiful green dress. 
#                                                  "E" 
#                    There's nothing wrong with green. 
#                                                  "E"
```

Loop over `sentences` and return a comma-separated string of classes that are present.

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr`, `purrr` and `tibble` possibility could be:

```
map(lst, ~ grepl(paste(.x, collapse = "|"), sentences, ignore.case = TRUE)) %>%
 transpose() %>%
 map_chr(~ enframe(.x) %>%
          summarise(name = paste(name[unlist(value)], collapse = ",")) %>%
          pull(name))

[1] "B,C,D" "D"     "D"     "A,D"   "C"     "C"     "E"     "E"
```

With lst being:

```
lst <- list(A = c("red"),
B = c("orange"),
C = c("yellow","yellowstone"),
D = c("blue"),
E = c("green"))
```